# why the domain system did not parse the root domain

Tags: domain-name-system

when I access the domain like `www.example.com`, it works fine. When I access the domain `example.com`, shows error:

```
This site can’t be reached Check if there is a typo in example.top.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

why the www domain works fine but the root domain did not work? I have already tried to using this command and clear the dns cache:

```
chrome://net-internals/#dns
```

I have already added the `example.com` listening on the server side. what should I do to make the root domain works? I have alread add the www record in the domain system, what record should I add with the root domain `example.com`?

Comment: "why the www domain works fine but the root domain did not work?" Because that is two separate names for the DNS, so they can be configured completely differently. One working has no bearing on the other working or not, and the opposite. In all cases like that your DNS provider should be your first step for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `example.com` does not have an A or AAAA record, you will get that error message. You need to update your DNS.

Comment: `A` or `AAAA` record :-)

Comment: I have A record with the www.example.com. how to add the A record for the example.com? there is no content before the domain, what content should I type into? @Tero Kilkanen

Comment: You didn't specify which DNS server you are using, but typically `@` (from BIND's  [`$ORIGIN` directive](https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/origin.html)) refers to the root domain.